# Is there a way to send JSON collection as a resource and not in the JavaScript as an object?

Tags: angularjs

I am new to Angular and trying to study it, so this might be basic. On my web server I have a list of MyObject. In every AngularJs example I see a serialized collection passed as a written object in JavaScript.

Something like this:

```
$scope.services = [
    {
        name: 'Web Development',
        price: 300,
        active:true
    },{
        name: 'Design',
        price: 400,
        active:false
    },{
        name: 'Integration',
        price: 250,
        active:false
    },{
        name: 'Training',
        price: 220,
        active:false
    }
];
```

This looks, in the final JavaScript, a bit too hard-coded.  Is there another way I can send this JSON? (i.e. in .Net I can use razor but I still need to dynamically build it as a string).

Is there another way I can send my JSON, but not in JavaScript? Perhaps as a resource and bind to it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's in the AngularJS tutorial [step 5](http://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial/step_05).